# openNLP - Name Finder Training for Addresses

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I am trying to isolate postal addresses from CVs (curriculum vitae).  The CVs are from many different countries so have no standard layout, formats, rhyme or reason to the addresses.

I have my raw data which has been segmented into sentences and tokens and is ready for markup.

Questions:

Whist City/town is of primary interest to me, should I mark up the entire address for best results?

```
eg blah blah blah <START:location>1 Stack Avenue, London, SE1 KTB<END> blah blah
eg blah blah blah <START:location>Hoch Strasse 21, Berlin 17009, Germany<END> blah blah
```

Given that the address I seek mainly appear in the top quarter of a CV, should I trim the training data to that 25% and do the same with the live data or will I get better results by keeping the documents as a whole and just tagging the bit I need?

Finally any ideas on the level of success I'm likely to have finding addresses from none structured documents?

Advice, help and alternative methods greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do have a recommendation how you could annotate for data more effectively. I created the framework [NLPf](https://gitlab.com/schrieveslaach/NLPf) which provides the annotation tool QPT which makes the annotation less exhausting and more effectively. Addtionally, you could train your models with `mvn compile`. If you have any questions, please, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to mark it up as

`1 Stack Avenue, <START:location> London, SE1 KTB <END> .
Hoch Strasse 21, <START:location> Berlin 17009, Germany<END>`

But you need to think about appropriate features.  For instance, in both your examples the previous word ends with a comma.  You obviously want the previous word, but maybe a feature like "number in the past 4 words.  Dont forget previous state.  You might want to keep a dictionary of words like "avenue, street" or their equivalent in other languages (Strasse?).
Good luck